# How to recursively send a nested hash the :[] method for any amount of levels?

Tags: ruby, hash

#### Context:

What I'm trying to do is make an `Rspec` shared_example called something like `update response` that checks a rails json response of an object and verifies that certain attributes are updated.  The json response may or may not have nested attributes. The keys cannot be known ahead of time.

#### Example:

Say I have a hash, `hsh = {one_deep: 123, nested: {a: 1, b: 2}}`:

I can dynamically send the hash a key if it's one level deep.

```
def get_value(some_key)
  hsh.send(:[], some_key) 
end

get_value(:one_deep) # => 123
```

I can access a nested hash if I hard code the method chain:

```
def get_value(some_key, another_key)
  hsh.send(:[], some_key).send(:[], another_key) 
end

get_value(:nested, :a) # => 1
get_value(:nested, :b) # => 2
```

#### Desired Endstate:

```
# The hash key could be 'n' levels deep
#
# This doesn't work... maybe use recursion somehow?
def get_value(*some_keys)
  some_keys.each do |key|
    hsh.send(:[], key)
  end
end


get_value(:nested, :a) # => should output 1
get_value(:nested, :b) # => should output 2
```

Comment: Well, that would be the answer! Nice. Please repost so I can mark as resolved.

Comment: `def get_value(*some_keys)` should be `def get_value(hsh, *some_keys)`.

Comment: My point above is that `hsh` defined outside the method is not visible within the method unless you make it an argument. As is, you will get an exception that `hsh` is not a local variable or method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using, Ruby 2.3.1, then you can use [`#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method to fetch the value of a key from nested Hash.

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby versions prior to 2.3.1 it's easy to implement [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig).

```
class Hash
  def dig(*keys)
    keys.reduce(self) { |obj, k| obj && obj[k] }
  end
end
```

If `obj[k]` is `nil`, `obj` will be set to `nil` and remain equal to `nil`.

Let's try it.

```
h = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { e: "cat" } } }
h.dig(:a)           #=> 1 
h.dig(:dog)         #=> nil 
h.dig(:b, :c)       #=> 2 
h.dig(:b, :d)       #=> {:e=>"cat"} 
h.dig(:b, :d, :e)   #=> "cat" 
h.dig(:b, :pig, :e) #=> nil
```